# Discriminat formula for number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K\subset L$ number fields, $ \mathcal{O}_K \subset \mathcal{O}_L $ their ring of integers take $ \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_L $  such that $L=K[\alpha]$ and $f(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. I'm trying to verify this identity in pag 2. of J.S. Milne's notes on class field theory

[image]

Since  $\mathcal{O}_L$ might not be free over $ \mathcal{O}_K$ he defines $\mathrm{disc}({\cal O}_L / \mathcal{O}_K)$ in the following way:

[image]

So if we note $A=\mathcal{O}_K$, $B={\cal O}_L$ and for $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime in  $A$,  $S= A-\mathfrak{p}$,$ A_{\mathfrak{p}}=S^{-1}A$ , $B_\mathfrak{p}=S^{-1}B$ and $l=[B:A[\alpha]]$. Since for any $\mathfrak{a}$ $A$-ideal we have $\mathrm{ord}_\mathfrak{p} (\mathfrak{a})=\mathrm{ord}_{\mathfrak{p } A_{\mathfrak{p}}} ( S^{-1} \mathfrak{a})$. What we have to prove is:

$
\mathrm{disc}(A_\mathfrak{p} [\alpha]/ A_\mathfrak{p} )= l^2 \,\, \mathrm{disc}(B_\mathfrak{p} / A_\mathfrak{p})
$ , as $A_\mathfrak{p}$-ideals.

Since $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a PID and both $B_\mathfrak{p}$ and  $A_\mathfrak{p} [\alpha]$ have rank $n=[L:K]$ over  $A_\mathfrak{p}$, we may find  $\{\gamma_1, \ldots ,\gamma_n \}$  a $A_\mathfrak{p}$-basis of $B_\mathfrak{p}$  and $d_1, \ldots , d_n \in A_\mathfrak{p}$ such that $\{d_1 \cdot \gamma_1, \ldots , d_n\cdot \gamma_n \}$ is an $A_\mathfrak{p}$-basis for $A_\mathfrak{p} [\alpha]$ and $ d_i \mid d_j $ for $i \leq j $.

Thus we have:

$
\mathrm{disc}(A_\mathfrak{p} [\alpha]/ A_\mathfrak{p} )= (\prod d_i)^2 \,\, \mathrm{disc}(B_\mathfrak{p} / A_\mathfrak{p})
$.

But I'm not able to prove that $\prod d_i A_\mathfrak{p} = l A_\mathfrak{p} $ except in the trivial case when $p\nmid l $ for $p \,\mathbb{Z}= \mathfrak{p} \cap \mathbb{Z} $. Thanks for any help.